# Reference to Inspector.CurrentItem causes reminders to keep coming back

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, office-interop

I'm creating a simple Outlook add-in to work with reminders.  When I create a meeting that includes a room and I refer to Inspector.CurrentItem in my new inspector event handler, a reminder is created that just comes back after dismissal.

I'm using Outlook 2013 and Visual Studio 2017.  If I don't include a room in the meeting invite, the reminder will dismiss properly.  I've boiled the problem down to the following code.  (If I comment out the reference to Inspector.CurrentItem, the reminder dismisses properly.)

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private Outlook.Inspectors inspectors { get; set; }
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectors = Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector +=
        new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
    }

    void Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        var currentItem = Inspector.CurrentItem; //Just referring to Inspector.CurrentItem causes a persistent reminder that won't go away.
    }
    ...
}
```

Due to administrative limitations, I've been unable to try possible fixes that involve clearing Outlook reminders on my machine.

Comment: I don't know about your original problem, but you need to take inspectors variable declaration up to the class level or it will be released by the GC and no events will fire.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko if you notice, it is just a reference to a class level object

Comment: No, your "inspectors" variable is declared on the local (ThisAddIn_Startup method) level. It must be declared on the class level.

Comment: Moved the inspectors property to class level as suggested.  Although it's a good idea, it didn't help the persistent reminder issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue of garbage collection as described in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2019/02/15/oom-net-part-2-outlook-item-leaks/).  (Outlook COM object garbage collection isn't automatic and has to be done manually.)

It was solved by adding:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentItem);
```